# SQL: histograms for multiple columns

Tags: sql

Given the following table:

```
Column A     Column B
    east          red
    west         blue
    east        green
```

I want to find out the of column values of each column and how many times each value is present in the table. Given the output above the result should look like:

```
A values   A value counts   B values   B value counts
    east                2        red                1
    west                1       blue                1
                               green                1
```

This is achievable by running `SELECT colX, count(colX) From Table GROUP BY colX` for each column. This is not a scalable solution if there is a complex WHERE condition since it needs to be executed for each query.

An alternative is to execute the complex where query once and compute the aggregations in the server code. But is there a single SQL query that can compute that?

Comment: Handle the A and B separately, perhaps a UNION ALL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function :

```
select cola, count(*) over (partition by cola) as a_count,
       colb, count(*) over (partition by colb) as b_count
```

This will count for both columns (`a & b`) with their values display.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries to aggregate, then `union all` and aggregate again to combine the results:

```
select max(a) as a, max(a_cnt) as a_cnt, max(b) as b, max(b_cnt) as b
from ((select a, count(*) as a_cnt, null as b, null as b_cnt,
              row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
       from t
       group by a
      ) union all
      (select null, null, b, count(*),
              row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
       from t
       group by b
      ) 
     ) ab
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle you can use user_tab_cols to generate the SQL for all columns in your table

```
        SELECT 'SELECT '
           || Listagg(column_name
                      ||',count(1) over (partition by '
                      ||column_name
                      ||') as '
                      ||column_name
                      ||'_cnt', ',')
                within GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)
           ||' FROM '
           ||'TEST_DATA'
    FROM   user_tab_cols
    WHERE  table_name = 'TEST_DATA'
```

Sample output is below

```
 SELECT ID,count(1) over (partition by ID) as ID_cnt,VALUE,count(1) over (partition by 
 VALUE) as VALUE_cnt FROM TEST_DATA
```